# Creating ubuntu 14.04 boot into external hard drive

Tags: 14.04, boot

I've tried to use `rufus` software to create Ubuntu 14.04 boot into external hard drive but `rufus` cannot recognize external hard drive as USB flash drives. Is there a proper way or software to create boot into external hard drive?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean to install ubuntu in the external drive?

Comment: Here is some guidance steps https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick have a look at this whether this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution with no need for other applications or software.

Just remove the connection of your internal storage and keep your external connected.

 Now just install Ubuntu 14.04 or whatever in the external hdd. 
Once you are finish connect your internal storage again.
Now you have a bootable external drive

If you really want to do it with a software. you can enjoy the vast:

[UUI : Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

[Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
sudo apt-get update`
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

[MultiSystem](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/)

[LiveUSB](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)

[YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)