# Installing Ubuntu on external HDD

Tags: 14.04, external-hdd

I want to install Ubuntu on an external HDD. Now, the only question that I want to get an answer to is that : Will it tamper with the original Windows installation in the HDD that is in my laptop? [ not on the external hdd ] And Will I be able to boot Windows, anyway, if I want to, by removing the external HDD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will **not** damage your Windows installation. Make sure that you are actually installing it in your external hard-disk (`/dev/sdb` or whatever) and you are actually installing the bootloader in this external hard-disk during the installation process. Here is a guide if you want a bit more [detail](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2013/10/23/how-to-install-ubuntu-13-10-on-an-external-hard-drive/).

Answer (score 3):

Sure, it will not affect your internal device and thus it has no effect on your Windows HDD.

Moreover just when you need to run the Windows you can easily just get rid of external device or easily you can use the boot options in your BIOS.

Read this for info [Creating ubuntu 14.04 boot into external hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615858/creating-ubuntu-14-04-boot-into-external-hard-drive/615910#615910)